# Using ViewPager the same way it works in android market (google play)

Tags: android, google-play, android-viewpager

I have a collection of products from different categories and I want to show the products of each category in different "pages" with the horizontal view swiping functionallity, like in [this image](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-T0ubrNZd4ro/TlOx2EZGnXI/AAAAAAAAAp0/p7PQWuJc8Ns/s400/MarketSwipe.png).

I tried with the example shown [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentPagerSupport.html), but I don't know if I have to use a FragmentPagerAdapter or a simple PagerAdapter. Every page must have the same layout, the unique thing that will change is the source of the data.

How can achieve that? Which could be the best option?

Comment: You might find this library useful= https://github.com/astuetz/android-viewpagertabs

Answer (score 3):

Use a FragmentPagerAdapter. See a clear example here of how to use it.

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Also note there's a free add-on library to indicate which page the user is on

http://www.viewpagerindicator.com

Comment: Thanks. I understood the example, but I still don't know what to do with adapters and layouts. I need only one layout, right? But I'll need an adapter or fragment for each of the categories?

Sorry I'm new in android development.

Comment: It depends on your application. You might have several Fragments defined, or you might use one and reuse it (if all the pages look the same). If you are new to Android I suggest you buy some books - until you train yourself, you will find it very hard to make progress.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PagerSlidingTabStrip library available on [Github](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStriphttps://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip
[image]